# How to run pkg-config for Qt5

Tags: qt, autotools, pkg-config

ALL,

How do I run pkg-config for Qt5?

Or there is some other script that will identify where Qt is installed?

And I'm talking about Qt - not QtE{mbedded}.

EDIT:

I think this needs some clarification. ;-)

I am trying to add this to a cross-platform project where Qt may not be installed on the system. I am using Anuta for development and already have Maefile, with which everything is built and ran correctly on GTK side. (I'm using the default `pkg-config --cflags gtk+3` to find where GTK includes are).

However if I can add something like above for Qt to identify where Qt Headers are, it would be great. That way I will need to maintain only one set of Makefile and won't need to keep updating it when I push/pull to/from GitHub.

TIA!!

Comment: As far as I am aware, Qt takes the position that `qmake` ought to be used to configure Qt-based projects for building.  Of course, `qmake` knows where to find the corresponding headers and libraries.  Although it is possible to build Qt-base projects by other means, I don't think Qt does anything to support that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, does this mean I can't have 1 makefile to build for both GTK and Qt, right? Because if `qmake` is not available - the build will fail... Or I am wrong?

Comment: No, that's not what I said at all.  Refer to "it is possible to build Qt-base[d] projects by other means".  I just said that I think it's futile to look for package-config data for Qt, or to look for any other, similar Qt build-configuration data aimed outside the `qmake` build system.  One can (and I have) built Qt software without using `qmake`, but doing so is an uphill battle.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Understood. So what is the best option - maintain 2 different Makefile;'s or...? I can probably try to install KDevelop (or whatever the new K/Qt IDE is), but is it a best option?

Comment: I would need much better perspective on the project to make a recommendation of that kind.  But I will offer a frame challenge: it is extremely uncommon for a GUI project to support multiple GUI toolkits.  Since Qt is apparently a secondary target for you, perhaps you should think about whether you actually want to go there at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, my project is uses wxWidgets which can be built with both GTK and Qt. Wherever, ne piece f it uses native stuff n Linux because the thing I need is not available in either GTK nr Qt. On GTK everything builds and runs fine, but I just tried to build Qt version and I need the way to identify the Qt placement., I hope it answers your question. Let me know if you need more info. But at this point I might just add the control I need to wxWIdgets.